# Why doesn't this button resize when the window is resized?

Tags: resize, widget, tcl, tk-toolkit

In the following Tcl/Tk script the button doesn't resize when the window is resized, why not?

```
ttk::button .b -text "Doesn't resize with window."
grid .b -column 0 -row 0 -padx 10 -pady 10 -sticky nesw
```

How can i get this working using the grid geometry manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to set the weight of the grid columns and rows.

```
grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1
% grid rowconfigure . 0 -weight 1
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11774196/13227